# Usage of "although" in this sentence

Tags: writing

"Many students complain about the pile of homeworks they have to do. Although, they fail to realize the importance homeworks in retention of information.."
is the usage of although acceptable / correct here?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Besides the incorrect use of the comma after and  the period before "although",  "homework" is a mass noun, and should not be pluralized.

Comment: What do you think, and why do think that?